# STL heap containing pointers to objects

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I have an `std::list<MyObject*> objectList` container that I need to sort and maintain in the following scenario:

- Each object has a certain field that supplies a cost (a float value for example). That cost value is used to compare two objects as if they were floating point numbers
- The collection must be ordered (ascending) and must quickly find the correct position for a newly inserted element.
- It is possible to delete the lowest element (in terms of cost) and it is also possible to *update* the cost of several arbitrarily positioned elements. The list must be then reordered as fast as possible, taking advantage of its already sorted nature.

Could I use any other stl container/mechanism to allow for the three behavioral properties? It pretty much resembles a heap and I thought using `make_heap` could be a good way to sort the list. I need to have a container of pointers, since there are several other data structures that rely on these pointers.

How then can I choose a better container that's also pointer friendly and allows sorting by looking at the comparison operators of the pointed types?

*CLARIFICATION*: I need an stl container that best fits the scenario and can successfully wrap pointers or references for that matter. (For example, I read briefly that the `std::set` container could be a good candidate, but I have no experience with it).

A current implementation, based on the below answers:

```
struct SHafleEdgeComparatorFunctor
    {
        bool operator()(SHEEdge* lhs, SHEEdge* rhs)
        {
            return (*lhs) < rhs;
        }
    };

std::multiset<SHEEdge*, SHafleEdgeComparatorFunctor>    m_edges;
```

Of course, the `SHEEdge` data structure has an overloaded operator:

```
bool operator<(SHEEdge* rhs) 
    {
        return this->GetCollapseError() < rhs->GetCollapseError();
    }
```

Comment: To me, it sounds like you've answered your own question: a heap seems like the perfect structure for your problem.

Comment: @NPE: I guess the question then becomes; "do any of the STL (or Boost) containers resemble a heap?"...

Comment: @NPE: ty, I edited the question and added the clarification for this case.

Comment: Have a look at [boost.flat_multiset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would indeed use `std::set`. The tricky bit in your requirements is to update existing elements.

A `std::set` is always sorted. You will have to either wrap your pointers in a class with a useful compare operator or you have to pass a comparison predicate to the set.

Then you get the sorted property automatically and you get constant time removal of the lowest element.

You also get updating of the cost value in log complexity: Simply remove the object from the set and re-add it. This will be as fast as it can be for a sorted container.

Inserting, and deleting is fast in a set.

Comment: I switched to `set` for now, but I'll consider and mildly benchmark the vector version as in MikePro's suggestion/answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd start using a **smart pointer** like `shared_ptr` instead of a *raw* pointer (raw pointers are good e.g. if they are *observing* pointers, like pointers passed as function parameters, but when you have *ownership* semantics, like in this case, it's better to use a smart pointer).

Then, I'd start with `std::vector` as a container.

So, try make it `vector<shared_ptr<MyObject>>`.

You can measure performance of it compared to `list<shared_ptr<MyObject>>`.

(Note also that `std::list` has kind of more overhead than `std::vector`, since it's a node-based container, and each node has some overhead; instead `std::vector` allocates a contiguous chunk of memory to store its data, in this case the `shared_ptr`s; so `std::vector` is also more "cache-friendly", etc.)

In general, `std::vector` offers very good performance, and it's a good option as a "*first choice*" container. In any case, your mileage may very, and the best thing is to **measure** performance (speed) to get a better understanding in your particular case.

Comment: How does that answer it? will it use the MyObject operators?

Comment: @Alon: You can use `std::sort()` to sort the `std::vector`, and pass a _lambda_ to implement the particular custom sorting logic.

Comment: Same with pointers:) but using shared_ptr is always a solid advice

Comment: Is there any guarantee that using `std::sort()` on a vector container that has most of its elements already ordered w.r.t. to the comparator will be as efficient as the text-book heap data-structure? (I'm not sure if it qsorts the vector again or not).

Comment: @teodron: I'd just write some code and **measure** speed: there are several factors that come into play, like `std::vector` being more efficient in inserting items when there is enough capacity vs. node-based containers overhead, etc. so I think you should consider the whole behavior, not only some single aspects.

Comment: "•The collection must be ordered (ascending) and must quickly find the correct position for a newly inserted element." vector?

Comment: A vector is definitely *not suitable* for this task. 

Inserting an element in a vector and sorting it with sort() has complexity N*log(N) (in the best case), while inserting into a set has a guaranteed log(N) complexity. Please do not confuse N*log(N) with log(N). Of course it depends on the size of the set/multiset. If the size is not much more than say 10 elements a vector will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly what you are asking, you are looking for the correct container to use.

Indeed `std::set` seems to be the correct container for the kind of things what you want to do, but it will depend on all the use cases

- Do you need to have O(1) access to the elements?
- What is the operation used that will have the most important cost?

`std::set` uses a key to sort the elements and doesn't allow having duplicates (if you want duplicates, have a look at `std::multiset`). When you add an element, it will automatically be inserted in the correct position. Generally you don't want to use raw pointers as the key, as objects can be null.

Another alternative could be to use a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr>>`, as @MikePro said, it is a good practice to have the pointers inside smart pointers, to prevent having to manually delete them (and avoid any memory leak in case of an exception for example). If you use a vector, you will have to use functions like `std::sort`, `std::find` present in `<algorithm>` header or `std::vector::insert`.

Generally this image helps finding your container. It's not perfect (as you have to know a bit more than what is displayed) but it usually does its job well:

[image: standard containers choice]

Comment: +1 for the flowchart - O(1) access time is always an ideal/nice to have nobody would turn down. I'm oscillating between set and vector, but I decided to currently go with the set version and see how efficient that is.